# Do I need to add every version of Python to PATH?

Tags: python, macos, shell, pip, path

I've been getting this error when using pip to install:
"WARNING: The script foo is installed in '/Users/bar/Library/Python/3.9/bin' which is not on PATH."

Do I need to remember to add to PATH everytime I update to a new version of Python and everytime I update to a new shell? What's a permanent solution?

Comment: how are you installing .. whatever you're installing?

Comment: @ti7 using pip.

Comment: Use virtual environments, adding multiple versions of python to `PATH` is just gonna cause problems.

Comment: recommend using `/path/to/correct/python3 -m pip install` instead of just `pip`

Answer (score 2):

it doesn't require to add every version of python the path environment.you do need to add the directory containing the Python executable to the path if you want to run python or its associated tools(pip).
few approaches:
1.Add Python to path:
There is an option to add python to the path during the installation,make sure to check that
2.Manually add Python to PATH:
you can do it manually if you had installed python without adding it to path
On Windows, you can go to System Properties > Advanced > Environment   Variables, and then add the path to the Python executable (eg:C:\Python39) to the path variable.
On Unix-based systems (Linux or macOS), you can modify your shell configuration file
3.Use a virtual environment:
Instead of relying on system-wide Python installations, you can use virtual environments for your projects. This way, each project can have its own isolated Python environment.
Use tools like virtualenv (for Python 2) or venv (for Python 3) to create and manage virtual environments.
Activating a virtual environment automatically adjusts the path for the current shell session, so you don't worry about varying versions.

Regarding updating to newer versions of python,the path need to be updated manually or reinstall it with giving path while installing it.

Regarding updating your shell, as long as the path modification is in a shell configuration file (e.g:.bashrc), it should persist across its updates.